# What does this function returns exactly?

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

I want to know exactly what this function returns. Does it return a null ?

```
function create_test()
{
    return;
}


$size = array();
$size = create_test(); // array is null ??
```

Comment: Did you try the code? Why do you have two assignments anyways?

Comment: `Does it return a null?` Yes.

Comment: i have 2 asignments because i like to declare my variables... even though i know that php does it for me... i'm a grown men, i can assign my own vars...

Comment: @Marco This has nothing to do with variable declaration. IMHO it is just noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no return value is specified, it returns `null`. The `return` statement here is optional since it does not return any value and is located at the end of the function. You can use the `return` statement to jump out of the function explicitly without necessarily reaching the end of the function.

See [Returning values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) and [Returning without argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: that's why ive asked the question coz php docs is saying: "If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned." and i'm not omiting the return..so php note is confusing

Comment: See the second note in this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: because your not giving return an argument to return

Comment: @Dagon it's clearer now! they omitted the part about the argument

Comment: @KevinPaladin that one os much clearer... thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will return `NULL` `var_dump()` the code

Code -

```
<?php

function create_test()
{
    return;
}


$size = array();
$size = create_test(); 
var_dump($size);
```